# "user_role" or "role_user" - naming join tables

Tags: sql, naming-conventions

Usually, join (many to many) tables are named after the types they join - if a table joins `users` to `roles`, its name would contain both `user` and `role` (i.e. `user_role`).

Is there a naming convention that defines which word / type should come first?

---

EDIT: Having a convention means knowing the name without having to remember it. Please, try to understand that before voting for closing the question for being not constructive.

Comment: If it is one to many (many roles for one user), probably `user` would come first.  If it is many to many, I don't think it matters at all.  This is subjective though - certain frameworks like Ruby on Rails have important conventions for this kind of thing, but it is really up to you if you are not constrained by conventions like that.

Comment: Subjective; just be consistent. I have seen "A_B" (alphabetically sorted), but I prefer "Primary_Secondary" where there is such a natural relationship: e.g. User is the "primary" subject/noun. Also, I prefer plural forms, so I would have "users_roles".

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, it is many to many and it does matter. Having a convention means knowing the name without having to remember it.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev And conventions are subjective (which are generally "Not Constructive" when asked in questions) - there is no Defacto-Guide for SQL/MySQL in this regard :-) Book A will say do it this way, and Advocate B will say to do it that way.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev I mean it doesn't matter to anyone but you and your team. You can choose and settle on whichever convention is most meaningful to you.  I didn't mean to imply that a convention isn't important.

Comment: @pst, I know it is. I'm looking for arguments that would help me (and, hopefully, not just me) decide wich convention I should go for.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Unfortunately, such "discussion" style questions are frowned upon per the FAQ. (There are a few cases where conventions can be backed by objective rules, such as Java naming conventions, but SQL has no such reference.)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I understand that, but should I throw dices about it?

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Of course not :) Read some books. Pick a form *you prefer* and then build an argument for, as well as a case against counter proposals. Then get everyone to agree on/follow a particular convention for the project(s).

Comment: @pst, Can you be sure that there are no objective arguments that can be made?

Comment: @EmanuilRusev If you have multiple many to many relationships with users, then I would put users first in all of them.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev Because there is no "gold standard" or "object reference" for SQL table naming conventions. I have said what I prefer/use (note that I would frown upon singular names, showing how divided the subject is!).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, This is the kind of answer I'm looking for. You should write it as an answer to the question.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski But that is easily argued against - e.g. can't a *Role* participate in multiple relationships as well? (Roles_Users, Roles_Permissions, etc? I would use Users_Roles, Roles_Permissions, but the counter-case holds that the number of relationships does not necessarily establish naming.)

Comment: @pst Precisely, and that's why I CV'd as not constructive :)

Comment: @pst, There should be at least a few arguments that can be made on the subject and I believe knowing them would be constructive.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski and @pst, How about putting the older type first? You have `user`. You decide to introduce `roles`. You need a join table. Type `user` existed before type `role`, so you name the table `user_role`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1:n it is user_role.

In m:n I'd use the more important one first, and in this case the stronger term is user IMHO, as you usually assign roles to users, not vice-versa.

The role does not make sense without a user, but a user makes sense without a role.